# speech recognition to launch my app

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

is there any action available to listen audio so that when I say my preset word like "good morning", it should launch my app. It means I want to make a broadcast receiver with the action define 'listen audio' as any one say "good morning" like "Ok google", my receiver should listen this and do my task.

Please help me that will be great.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#AppProvided

Answer (score 0):

In such case first of all you have to make one Service which will call when your device is started and it will continuously running mode(i.e At Boot time)

In the Service you will have implement Speech to Text functionality to convert "Good Morning" accent from speech to text

Once your service identify a specific Accent then you will launch your app!!

I hope it will help to you.